# how to set apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent on a SegmentedRow

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I need to have the segments of a `SegmentedRow` to be autosized by their text labels.
My idea was to use:

```
segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```

but can't get a reference to `segmentedControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access to `cell`, and then access to segmented control on `SegmentedRow` with Eureka something like this

```
    <<< SegmentedRow<String>("segments"){
        $0.cell.segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
    }
```

I hope this helps you, regards

Comment: Thanks, that helped yes.